# How to change values in a list while using for loop in Python? (without using index)

Tags: python

I'm trying to take two lists and use one list to make changes in the second list as the following code shows:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [0,0,0,0,0]

for aA, bB in zip(a,b):
    bB = aA*4
    
print(b)
```

I get the result b = [0,0,0,0,0],
I want b = [4,8,12,16,20]

I know that you shouldn't modify containers while iterating with a for loop. But is there any work-around in python to be able to get the intended result of modifying a container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python unlike many other languages is dynamically typed as in you don't need to initialize prepopulated arrays(lists) before populating them with data. Also a standard convention is list comprehensions which in lamens are in-line loops that return a list.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [num * 4 for num in a]
```

This is equivilent to:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = []
for num in a:
    b.append(num * 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
b.append( aA*4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why *not* use index?

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    b[i] = a[i]
```

The standard advice is "don't change a list *while you're iterating over it*". We say this because if you add or remove an element then the iterator will start doing weird hard-to-predict things. But that's not what's happening here: we're iterating over `a` and changing `b`, knowing in advance they're the same size, so there's no undefined or hard-to-understand behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The values you want to put into `b` only depend on `a`, so there is no reason to initialize and iterate on `b`. You could do either:

```
# build list b as you go
b = []
for aA in a:
    b.append(aA*4)
print(b)
```

or

```
# use a list comprehension
b = [aA*4 for aA in a]
print(b)
```